# Overriding DebugSymbols flag in Custom Targets

Tags: c#, vb.net, msbuild

All my `proj` (C# & VB) files import a custom targets file.

In here I want to override the `<DebugSymbols>true</ DebugSymbols>` irrespective of which $(Configuration)|$(Platform) I am compiling.  (To save me the effort of setting it in every new project which gets created.)

I've tried setting this property inside *and* outside of a target in my custom targets file and I've tried tacking a target onto `BeforeTargets="CoreCompile"` - and setting it there. In both cases it is getting set - as I can message it out later.

What I want, of course is for `CoreCompile` to always set `/debug:full` when it constructs the call to `[vbc|csc].exe`.

But I just can't seem to get the `.pdbs` if I set `<DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>` in a projects's Release configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the DebugType property as well, for instance

```
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
```